# data structures and algorithms e-books

Tags: algorithm

Where can I find e-books on Data Structures and Algorithms? I am currently reading "Computer Algorithms: Introduction to design and Analysis" by Sara Baase and Allen Van Gelder. I would like to have additional information to supplement what's in this book. Also some references on worst-case analysis would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By far my favourite algorithm textbook is [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/), by Steven Skiena. Very easy to read, very practical, and extremely useful. The first half of the book is a general treatment of algorithm theory, with lots of practical examples. The second half is a huge library of common problems, what algorithms can be used to tackle them, and comprehensive lists of references. You won't be disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Robert Sedgewick's](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/) Algorithms books. The original one used Pascal and is nice because it does not get boggled down in language issues.

Answer (score 2):

[Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937)

[The Art of Computer Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485419) - by Donald Knuth (hard read, but well worth it, not recommended for a first algorithms book)

[Concrete Mathemetics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025) - By Donald Knuth (understanding the math behind algorithms)

I don't know if e-book versions are available for these, but if they are...these books will definitely give you the theory behind worst-case, and asymptotic analysis of algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Aho, Hopcroft and Ullman - Design And Analysis Of Computer Algorithms 
A classic.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cc/Clrs.jpg))</sub>

[**Introduction to Algorithms** by CLRS (second edition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) is pretty much the standard textbook today for these subjects.

Comment: IIRC, the first edition was included in the Dr. Dobbs Essential Books on Algorithms and Data Structures CD-ROM, along with 8 or 9 other books and some Dr. Dobbs articles. Should still available, but be aware that the books are HTML prepared some years ago for an old Internet Explorer version, and don't all display well even in current IE, let alone Firefox etc.

Comment: I believe this is also the standard text for the MIT courseware 6.046J Introduction to Algorithms course.

Answer (score 2):

The [Algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Main_Page) wiki is a decent resource.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this counts as an "e-book", but I am rather fond of the wikibooks project. It is a bit disorganized, but has everything you need. Plus, built-in links to wikipedia!
[linky](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category:Algorithms_and_data_structures)