# Is Algorithm Design Manual a good book for a beginner in algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

I've a good idea of what Big-O is, and I also know a few basic sorting algorithms, although, for some reason, I was never comfortable with them, and I keep forgetting them. I've been programming for 4 years in Java, Python, C and C++; I've been a decent programmer. Now, I want to move beyond learning programming languages and start learning algorithms.

I tried 'Introduction to Algorithms' by Cormen et al. but the Math is too dense for me (or, may be, I'm too dense for the Math in that book).

Now, I'm planning to take up Algorithm Design Manual by Steve Skiena. Would you recommend it for my situation? Do you have any other recommendations if you think this is not the one for me?

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249465/data-structures-and-algorithms-e-books/1249676#1249676

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I would certainly recommend the Skiena book.  You've started to learn about algorithms, you should start to learn algorithms too.

To whoever edited this answer and replaced the last occurrence of the word *algorithms* with the word *mathematics*: I meant *algorithms* when I wrote this answer, I still mean *algorithms*, replacing the word with *mathematics* materially changes the answer.  If you think that mathematics is what OP should learn, post your own answer to that effect.  If you had troubled to read the commentary below you would understand why I chose the word *algorithms* and not *mathematics*.

Comment: "You've started to learn about algorithms, you should start to learn algorithms too." - Is it me or this doesn't make a lot of sense?!

Comment: It made sense to me. It's another way of saying, "Instead of talking about algorithms, start learning it."

Comment: Learning about algorithms means learning stuff such as complexity, iteration, recursion, divide-and-conquer, branch-and-bound, etc.

Learning algorithms means knowing what quicksort, bubblesort, Dijsktra's algorithm, Kruskal's algorithm, etc are.

Comment: Learning algorithms means being apply to recognize a problem with a viable algorithm solution, adapting the algorithm if necessary and implementing it ad-hoc. Try Kandane's Algorithm given a matrix instead of an array--you'll know what I mean.

Comment: Definitely recommend Skiena as the best book for Algorithms and Data Structures. And if you are currently in touch with C, it's just pure gem. Only issue is that C is not a mainstream language and Skiena's book follows C throughout. It has excellent discussions on algorithms - their strengths and weaknesses. You will especially enjoy the war stories. Although, everyone should be well versed in C, I don't think it's necessary to get distracted by pointer level details. This is the only reason that you should Sedgewick's 4rth edition with you. Read from Skiena but implement from Sedgewick.

Comment: @Srikanth - So which book did you finally end up using as your main book ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 I went with Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick & Kevin Wayne and their companion video lectures on Coursera (without which I'd have not made very far).

Comment: @Srikanth - Thanks. Did you use any other resource/book as your main resource along with sedgewick's book ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 I'd say the videos were my main resource and I actually refer to the book very infrequently. Along with this video series, I'm finding Elements of Programming Interviews in Java really helpful in solidifying what I'm learning by connecting the algorithms with problems. For someone like me who's a Java programmer, I'm finding these two resources most comfortable.

Answer (score 16):

I would recommend against "Algorithm Design Manual" for your purposes and for skimming Cormen or Wikipedia instead.

After a short introduction to basic algorithmic topics, pages 171-437 don't really teach you neither about how algorithms work nor how to design them, but more about what algorithms exist and where to find their implementations (sometimes it refers you to implementations you will need to buy, like in the section on Linear Programming)

For example there are 3 pages on matrix multiplication, which give a few examples of what it is useful for, present the naive O(N<sup>3</sup>) algorithm, and mention there are better algorithms like Strassen's O(N<sup>2.81</sup>) (without describing the algorithm), and recommend that you to use the LAPACK library for it.

So if you want to learn how algorithms work, rather than what algorithms exist and where to find their implementations, I again, recommend against "Algorithm Design Manual".

Comment: You cannot "skim" Cormen.

Comment: You mentioned pages 171-437. Which book ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2: "Algorithm Design Manual"

Answer (score 3):

I bought Algorithm Design Manual recently and have only gone though first few chapters. It is a great book but in my opinion (from what I have read so far):

(1) it is no less dense than Cormen's.

(2) it is more about practical implementations of algorithms than learning algorithms.

Comment: It is much less dense than Cormen.

Comment: Sounds perfect if one's job does not involve creating brand new or complex data structures and algorithms like Page rank algorithm, Tries data structure etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it (or your employer pays for it), and you program in Java, I'd suggest: **[Data Structures and Algorithms in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814239232)**.  It covers the same topics you find in other books, but it makes it easy to apply an understand if your used to programming in Java.  For example, C++ data structure books don't usually spend a great deal of time on hashes, as structures based on hashes aren't as common in C++ programming.  In Java, however, hashes are very common, and every object has a hashCode method.  The book combines a good mix of theory and practice.

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51w6USIIpxL._SL160_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51w6USIIpxL._SL160_.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a down to earth approach with a little maths thrown in try [Algorithms in a Nutshell](http://www.i-programmer.info/bookreviews/20-theory/93-algorithms-in-a-nutshell.html)  - I for one actually *enjoyed* reading it which is more than I can say for the knuth masterwork. (Ok there are a few pages in knuth that were enlightening enough to be called *fun*.)

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend [Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++ by Mark Allen Weiss](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032144146X).

Comment: Why do you recommend this book ? What distinguishes it from the commonly recommended books like CLRS ?

Answer (score -2):

No, I don't think so. Try [Data Structures and Algorithms in 24 Hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672316331) by Robert Lafore.

Answer (score -4):

Here are a couple of recommendations:

- Aho & Ulman - "Algorithms And Data Structure"
- Vhirt
- Donald E. Knuth - "The Art of Computer Programming"

Answer (score -4):

"Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson & Rivest. See [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Second-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262032937](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937)