# Good references for algorithm efficiency

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, reference

I want to fundamentally learn algorithm efficiency by self study (hopefully both in how a program can make best use of hardware and in designing an algorithm). I wanted to know about some good books on this topic. I write my programs in c.

Comment: Some good algorithm book suggestions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249465/data-structures-and-algorithms-e-books (they will all cover efficiency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll recommend the book [Algorithms in C, Parts 1-4: Fundamentals, Data Structures, Sorting, Searching](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201314525), the author Robert Sedgewick has a magic power to explain hard things easily understood. The book though not well edited, is the best reference on data structure and algorithms in C I've read.

Quoting from editorial reviews:

> Highlights

- Expanded coverage of arrays, linked lists, strings, trees, and other
  basic data structures Greater emphasis on abstract data types (ADTs)
  than in previous editions
- Over 100 algorithms for sorting, selection, priority queue ADT
  implementations, and symbol table ADT (searching) implementations
- New implementations of binomial queues, multiway radix sorting,
  Batcher's sorting networks, randomized BSTs, splay trees, skip lists,
  multiway tries, and much more
- Increased quantitative information about the algorithms, including
  extensive empirical studies and basic analytic studies, giving you a
  basis for comparing them
- Over 1000 new exercises to help you learn the properties of
  algorithms

> Whether you are a student learning the algorithms for the first time or a professional interested in having up-to-date reference material, you will find a wealth of useful information in this book.

As a reader, I'll say it deserves this accomplishment.